# php export mysql data with dynamic columns to csv

Tags: php, mysql

iam new to php, i know how to export mysql results with static columns to csv, but in some cases i will have to export dynamically without specifying the column names. i have tried this below, i would need help to make this work please.

**PHP**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'test_export_to_csv'){


$head_qry = mysql_query("SELECT `header_display_name` FROM expense_heading WHERE expense_id='$expense_id' order by col_order");

$columnValues = Array();

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($head_qry) ) {

  $columnValues[] = $row['columnname'];

}
$filename = "uploads/reports/".$invoice_id.".csv";
$file = fopen($filename, 'w+');

fputcsv($file,$columnValues);   

$data_qry="SELECT $columnValues from invoice_detail where invoice_id='$invoice_id'";

$data_result=mysql_query($data_qry);
while($result=mysql_fetch_assoc($data_result)){
    $report_array=array($result[$columnValues]);
    fputcsv($file, $report_array);
}
fclose($file);

if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression'))
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');


header("Pragma: public"); // required
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false); // required for certain browsers
header("Content-Type: $ctype");

// change, added quotes to allow spaces in filenames
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($filename)."\";" );
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filename));
readfile("$filename");
exit();  
}
```

Comment: 1. **Don't** use the **deprecated and insecure** `mysql_*`-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead. 2. **You are open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)** and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries, which can be used if you use the above mentioned MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: Where are the variables `$expense_id` and `$invoice_id` defined?

Comment: `$columnValues` is an array. You definitely need to use `implode` to pass it to query text.

Comment: `$result[$columnValues]` is something wierd too.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, thank you will use MySQLi

Comment: @u_mulder thank you, will try `implode`

Comment: @u_mulder `$data_qry="SELECT `".implode('`,`', array_keys($columnValues))."`";` could you help how to while loop `fputcsv`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose something like this should work:

```
$columnValues = Array();

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($head_qry) ) {
  $columnValues[] = $row['columnname'];
}
$filename = "uploads/reports/".$invoice_id.".csv";
$file = fopen($filename, 'w+');

fputcsv($file,$columnValues);   

// don't use `array_keys`
$columnValuesStr = implode(', ', $columnValues);

$data_qry = "SELECT $columnValuesStr from invoice_detail where invoice_id='$invoice_id'";

$data_result = mysql_query($data_qry);
while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($data_result)) {
    // `$result` already an array which holds values of selected fields,
    // you can pass it directly to `fputcsv`
    fputcsv($file, $result);
}
```